# Всем привет! Как можно реализовать обработчик удачного платежа в aiogram 3.3.0 на Python?

Tags: python, aiogram, aiogram-3.x

```
@dp.message(content_types=ContentType.SUCCESSFUL_PAYMENT)
async def successful_payment(message: types.Message):
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Магический фильтр F](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/dispatcher/filters/magic_filters.html) принимает `message`, а раз в нём есть атрибут `successful_payment`, то мы можем его проверить:

```py
@dp.message(F.successful_payment)
async def successful_payment(message:Message):
    for j,k in message.successful_payment:
        print(f"{j} = {k}")
```

Comment: А Message мы откуда импортируем?

Comment: from aiogram.types import Message

Comment: Вместо Message я прописал types.Message. Спасибо!